# Factorization in the Omnific Integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, surreal-numbers

I'm wondering if there's been any work done on prime factorizations of Omnific integers as products of prime Omnific integers.

I suspect that each Omnific integer has a unique prime factorization, and that this can be lifted from the fact that every ordinal has a unique decomposition into other prime ordinals with respect to Hessenberg multiplication (not recursive multiplication) -- I was just wondering if any work had been done on this subject that perhaps delved a bit deeper than this surface level observation.

Comment: Isn't $\omega$, $\omega^{1/2}$, $\omega^{1/4}$, $\omega^{1/8}$, ... an infinite descending chain of divisors in omnific integers? Are there any prime omnific integers (other than usual integers) in the first place?

Comment: In *An introduction to the theory of surreal numbers*, Harry Gonshor does a quick study of arithmetic properties of $Oz$. He does not find any non trivial (i.e. non integer) prime omnific integer, and proves some results giving little hope that they exist.

Comment: I believe that there is a correspondence between Omnific Integers and cantor normal forms with possibly negative integer coefficients (think Grothendieck group over $O_n$ with Hessenberg operations) -- I'll be publishing a paper in the next couple of weeks that clearly elucidates this relationship, however these normal forms factor much the same as polynomials in base $\omega$.

If $\omega^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is an Omnific integer however, I have no idea what normal form this would correspond to -- perhaps I am mistaken that every Omnific integer corresponds to such a normal form.

Comment: For example, any delta-number is a prime ordinal with respect to the Hessenberg operations, so for example $\omega$ is prime but $\omega^2-4$ is not prime since $\omega^2-4=(\omega+2)(\omega-2)$.

Comment: But the Grothendick group of the ordinals under natural arithmetic is not isomorphic to the underlying group of $Oz$ which for instance is "almost divisible" in the sense that for $z \in Oz$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$, there is $z' \in Oz$ and $m \in \{0;...n-1\}$ such that $n.z' = z+m$. The other group is not. So you can't expect the rings to be isomorphic.

Comment: Ah, thank you -- this clarifies things for me quite a bit.

Comment: Indeed, Oz is an integer part of No: every surreal number is within distance 1 of an omnific integer. And No is the fraction field of Oz.

Comment: To @nombre, who wrote "In An introduction to the theory of surreal numbers, Harry Gonshor does a quick study of arithmetic properties of $Oz$. He does not find any non trivial (i.e. non integer) prime omnific integer, and proves some results giving little hope that they exist." - Conway given an example of a prime infinite omnific integer on page 46 of "On Numbers And Games," where he says that the integer $\omega + \omega^{1/2} + \omega^{1/3} + \omega^{1/4} + ... + 1$ is prime, with his infinite summation having some meaning. So I am curious how Gonshor reconciles this with that.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I think I remember Gonshor introducing this as a claim or conjecture of Conway. As far as I know, that this number is prime was only proved later by Alessandro Berarducci.